# Error when updating to material design

Tags: android, material-design

I am trying to update my project to use the new MaterialDesign libs and I am getting the following error:

> /demo/debug/values/values.xml:1095: error: Attribute
>   "selectableItemBackgroundBorderless" has already been defined

I'm using an internal lib with the following dependencies:

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 21
buildToolsVersion '21.1'

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "xxx.xxx.xxx"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 19
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.1.11'
}
```

I am stuck, please help!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to try

```
dependencies {
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.+"
}
```

as the android developer blog states.
http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html#setup

Comment: It seems like a bug.. when i add both support-v4 and support-v7-appcompat as jars everything is ok, but when i add them as dependencies i get the error above...

Comment: @user2906978 where did you get the jars?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. I find that my project has a custom attribute name called selectableItemBackgroundBorderless, delete it. The project works now. :)